# Facing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'"

Tags: gramex

Using Gramex on local, trying to access the main page. Getting this error. Screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

desktop-login: ignoring missing handler DBAuth with this error

Comment: Show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBAuth is available in enterprise edition. So please do

> pip install gramexenterprise